# Study the convergence of the function series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4})$.

I thought about 2 ways it can be done.

One way is to try and calculate the partial sum of the series so we can see what is its limit.

Another way is to use the fact that if we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ and we find a sequence $a_n$ so that

$|f_n(x)| \leq a_n$

and

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent

then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is convergent.

Now, we know that $arctan : \mathbb{R} -> (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ but if we take $a_n = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is divergent, but maybe there is a sequence that is bigger than $|arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4})|$ but it is convergent.

Can you help me out to see how to study the convergence of this function series?

Comment: Note that $\arctan$ is increasing and $\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}$ has a maximum for $x=n^2$. This allows you determine if the convergence is uniform or not.

Comment: @Winther How do I show that, let's say $x = n^2$ is a maximum?I think I need to study the monotony of the function to show that, right?

Comment: For example take derivative $=0$ to find extremal points. Also note that if you show $|f_n(x)| \leq a_n$ for some $a_n$ where $\sum a_n$ converges then you don't only show that $\sum f_n(x)$ is convergent, but that the convergence is uniform (this is [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test))

Comment: @Winther Yes, that's what I thought about. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $x \ge 0$, Using AM-GM inequality we have: $x^2+n^4 \ge 2xn^2\implies \dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^4}\le \dfrac{1}{n^2}\implies \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}\right)\le \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ ( note: $\tan^{-1}(\theta) \le \theta, \theta \ge 0$ ,and $\tan^{-1}(\theta)$ is a increasing function of $\theta$. For $x < 0$, use $\tan^{-1}(-x) = -\tan^{-1}(x)$.And the comparison test shows the series convergent.

Comment: Do I need to take 2 separate cases, for $x<0$ and $x>0$? I think that if I use absolute value I do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

We have that for any $x\neq 0$

$$\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}\right) \sim \frac{2x}{n^4}$$

therefore the series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: I thought about the fact that $arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}) \leq arctan(\frac{2x}{n^4})$, but then again, why $arctan(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}) \sim \frac{2x}{n^4}$? Are you using the fact that if $lim_{n->\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ exists then $a_n$ and $b_n$ have the same nature?

Comment: @Ghost We are using that as $y \to 0 \quad \frac{\arctan y}{y}\to 1$ and then [imit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: @Ghost That is for $n$ large $\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}\right) $ behaves as $\frac{2x}{x^2+n^4}$ and the latter converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.